# Bi Direction association in C++

Tags: c++

I've been trying to define two classes

```
class state03: public state
{
public:
    std::string name;   
    state03(bool inAcceptState, bool inRejectState)
    {
        setRejectState(inRejectState);
        setAcceptState(inAcceptState);
        name="State 03";
    }

    state * evalNextState(char input)
    {
         if(input==' ')
        {
            return this;
        }
         if(isalpha(input) || input=='_')
         {
             return new state04(false,false);
         }
        return new RejectState();
    }
};

class state04: public state
{
public:
    std::string name;
    state04(bool inAcceptState, bool inRejectState)
    {
        setRejectState(inRejectState);
        setAcceptState(inAcceptState);
        name="State 04";
    }
    state * evalNextState(char input)
    {
        if(isalnum(input) || input=='_')
        {
            return this;
        }
        if(input==',')
        {
            return new state03(false,false);
        }
        return new RejectState();
    }
};
```

and since the compiler scans the code top to bottom i receive this compilation error that class state04 is undefined as it's defined after class state03...

so how can I achieve the bi direction relation?

Answer (score 4):

You should move your implementation details in a separate file, which is the best and easiest way in that case:

**state03.h**

```
class state03 : public state {
   // ...
   state * evalNextState(char input);
}
```

**state04.h**

```
class state04 : public state {
   // ...
}
```

**state03.cpp**

```
#include "state03.h"
#include "state04.h"

state * state03::evalNextState(char input) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: I've tried the forward declaration but since I'm using the constructor of the class before I actually define it, I receive another compilation error.

Comment: user1043565: Just separate your declaration from your implementation, that is the proper way. I removed the forward declaration from the answer, it doesn't really apply in your case since you are calling the `state04` constructor with arguments (I missed that the first time around). As such, trying to forward declare `state04` will result in an *invalid use of incomplete type* error.

Comment: when I sperated the method implementation of the header file I received this error "'this' : can only be referenced inside non-static member functions". any ideas?

Comment: @user1043565: Can you add the updated code to the question? This shouldn't happen if done properly.

Comment: thanks a lot for your support, you are right, I didn't specify the class am working on in the method definition, and that's y the compiler sees the new method as a static block.

Answer (score 0):

Take the implementations out of the class definitions and move them to an implementation file.